# ImportError: No module named cv2. But running apt-get command shows that python-opencv is already installed

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

Even though I tried out the solutions given for the same type of questions concerning the same error, nothing worked. When I try to run the script it gives this import error. But surprisingly when I try

> apt-get install python-opencv

I get this message:

> python-opencv is already the newest version.

This is what puzzles me. If it is installed, why can't it be imported?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very strange, I tried to import cv2 in Xubuntu 16.04 after I have installed python-opencv and it works fine. Could you give more details of the environment where you're running it. Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @Nurzhan. No. I didn't use virtualenv. BTW i'm using debian 8.

Comment: Are you using python3.x ?

Comment: @3kt. No. Its 2.7

Comment: @user5103877 Have you installed libopencv-dev?

Comment: @Nurzhan NO. I didn't.

Comment: @Nurzan . I tried to run it again after installing libopencv-dev. But sadly there is no positive result

Comment: @user5103877 I need to see the output of `sudo dpkg-query -L python-opencv`

Comment: /.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-opencv
/usr/share/doc/python-opencv/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-opencv/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py

Comment: type `echo $PYTHONPATH` in the terminal and paste the output

Comment: ok thats strange. It gives a blank space

Comment: type in terminal `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` (or choose another text editor of your choice) and set the variable `$PYTHONPATH` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Then when you're done type `source ~/.bashrc` and see if you can `import cv2` now

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the library python-opencv is not installed in the default directory. That is why your interpreter cannot find it.

When dealing with python projects it's recommended to use virtualenv. It will allow you to create separate python environments and not mess them up. Then install pip and use it to install python packages rather than apt-get install inside of your virtual environment.

In your case you need to run:

```
sudo dpkg-query -L python-opencv
```

It will output the directories to where the python-opencv library was installed. And the add that path to PYTHONPATH in your .bashrc file (most likely it is .bashrc in Debian):

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/the/python/libraries"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Then run `. .bashrc` in your home folder.

But it's not recommended to do that. As I've already said the cleaner way  is to use virtualenv and pip. In that case you don't need to mess up with PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I did what you said and got the following error :    Traceback (most recent call last): ...
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

Comment: @user5103877 It's better to remove what you've already installed. Read the tutorials on how to setup virtualenv in debian, install pip and use it to install packages instead of apt-get. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I believe I have both virtualenv and pip. @Nurzhan. There is another problem too. My wifi connection drops continuously and couldn't be fixed till now. (thats the next question I'll be posting soon because non of the answers for the alike problems worked). So uninstalling is not a good idea now.

Comment: @user Make sure you really have virtualenv and pip and that you know how to use them.